# Doubt in implementing Service

Tags: android

I have written a service To delete data from a table when data inputed into it(tblTest) as given below

```
public class service_helper extends Service {
    private DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

           return null;

     }

     @Override

     public void onCreate() {

           super.onCreate();

           Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this); 
         dbAdapter.open();


        String sqlTransaction = "Select test from tblTest where test > ?";
        dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this); dbAdapter.open();
         Cursor cursorTransaction = dbAdapter.ExecuteRawQuery(sqlTransaction, "-1");

         for (int i = 0; i < cursorTransaction.getCount(); i++) {

            String sql = "DELETE FROM tblTest WHERE test=" + i + " ";
            dbAdapter.ExecuteQuery(sql);    
         }



     }



     @Override

     public void onDestroy() {

           super.onDestroy();

           Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }

}
```

I have Started the service in the on create of main activity as  given below

startService(new Intent(this, service_helper.class));

The problem is that I can't do anything in my applicaion because of the service got stated.I cant navigate from my main form.Is it the Right way to implement Service ?

Will any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written that deletion in a runnable thread and called in the service

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement callback to get back to ur activity
kindly refer [Service call backs to activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026393/service-call-backs-to-activity-in-android) link

Hope it will help u.