# AIDL cannot find custom declared interface

Tags: android, aidl

I want to pass a Listener through a System Service in Android. I created my Listener Interface using AIDL.

Content of IStatusBarLostFocusCallback.aidl:

```
package com.android.internal.statusbar;

interface IStatusBarLostFocusCallback {
  void onLostFocus();
}
```

then I extended Androids IStatusBarService.aidl with following Function:

```
void setStatusBarLostFocusCallback(in IStatusBarLostFocusCallback listener);
```

and also imported my Interface (in the same directory)

```
import com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarLostFocusCallback;
```

In Androids StatusBarManagerService, I extended this Interface since I read to do this in this Thread: [Android remote service callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592990/android-remote-service-callbacks) like this:

```
public interface StatusBarLostFocusCallback extends IStatusBarLostFocusCallback {
    public void onLostFocus();
}
```

Now I want to set the Listener with the `setStatusBarLostFocusCallback` which is defined in `IStatusBarService.aidl` and implemented in `StatusBarManagerService.java`.

However, when I try to compile the Framework, I get the following Error

```
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/src/core/java/com/android/internal/statusbar/IStatusBarService.java:287: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IStatusBarLostFocusCallback
location: package com.android.internal.statusbar
com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarLostFocusCallback _arg0;
```

What have I missed. Do I have to write a `.java` for the `IStatusBarLostFocusCallback`? If so, what should be in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it now. I forgot to add my AIDL to the Build in `/frameworks/base/Android.mk` (I did forget to mention I am building the Source).
I now no longer extend the Interface but implement it like this:

```
mBarService.setStatusBarLostFocusCallback(new IStatusBarLostFocusCallback.Stub(){
    public void onLostFocus(){
        mHasStatusbarFocus = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you try as described like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html#ImplementTheInterface) ?

If yes, and this didn't work, you may implement methods from aidl like this, for example:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Class aClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());

Method method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
method.setAccessible(true);

ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
telephonyService.endCall();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution was another. I forget to Mention I build from Source, so I don't have to use reflection. I simply forget to add my Interface to the Build.