# Pass data through app android

Tags: java, android

I want to pass `Object` from `App1, App2, App3 --> AppG`. In particular:

`App1, App2, App3` can secure save `Object`.

`AppG` can read this `Object` and do stuff.

I read about `ContentProvider, Meta-Data, Parcelable, SharedPref` and so on but nothing do what I need, some of those required app signed with same key, other hasn't safe.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking but ContentProvider seems correct.

Comment: Otherwise, just write data to a public directory on the SD card

Comment: I need to write `Object` with listener and so on...In SD card isn't safe..

Comment: I don't know what "with listener" means

Comment: I mean with `OnClickListener` interface implementation for example

Comment: I don't think you can keep that interface across serialization

Comment: I want to save `Object` because this app called for example "client" can save their implementation of `Object`, so now app called for example "server" can read this implementation of `Object`

Comment: You need to provide code samples of what you have implemented. Throwing around abstractions like `Object, Client, Server and App` tells us nothing. People will just start recommending their favorite serialization frameworks, which is not an answer.

Comment: @DominicCerisano My Server Client etc is just an example...I can write general Object class and post here, but this doesn't matter...

Comment: Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to communicate between two apps but if you need:

1. **Pass an Object** that you've created (Not from Java/Android).
2. **Create a callback** (e.g `OnClickListener`) over IPC.

There are much less options that will work for you, **follow the next steps**:

1. Use [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) to speak between the apps. AIDL will provide a very raw mechanism to pass data between apps with different processes.
2. In-order to be able to pass your `Object` between processes [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678057/6028746) the `Parcel` [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).
3. To create a call back you need to create another parcelable object as your callback interface and set it as a return value([Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600690/6028746))

Comment: I got this error while generate .java file from .aidl `Error:Execution failed for task ':library:compileReleaseAidl'.` I build with API 25  and build tool 25.0.0