# How to enable IPC in Android Source Tree

Tags: java, android, jvm, android-source, dalvik

I am working in a project where different components in Android source tree need to communicate. For example, the accessibility service need to sends a request to ImageView class to notify when ever a new image view is instantiated.

I want to know some ways to handle theses scenarios, my broadcast receiver did not work. And it does not work without a context. Can you guys suggest some other approaches? If I implement memory file how I can handle notifications that some requests have been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Android internal components that run under the dalvik (or ART) communicate with each other through [AIDL's](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).
This mechanism will provide a very raw mechanism to pass data between apps with different processes.
AIDL also support creation of a callback - you will need to create another parcelable object as your callback interface and set it as a return value ([Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600690/6028746)).

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d54f3f41c4b41955b7b4382a08b97a356b31fde4/core/java/android/accessibilityservice) you can find a good example of the **accessibility service** implemanting the AIDL IPC mechanism.